# How I can stop agent reach an other netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I need a function of an agent against an agent which they stop when they reach each other
i tryed this psodo code

```
ask turtles [
   if heading = 90 with [pcolor = red]  [ stop ]
  ]
end
```

and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will stop if the patch ahead (whatever heading the turtle is facing) is red:

```
ask turtles
[ if [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 = red [stop]
]
```

If you want a particular direction, such as your code implies with `heading = 90` then you need something like:

```
ask turtles
[ if [ pcolor ] of patch-at-heading-and-distance 90 1 = red [stop]
]
```

In response to the additional information that the check should be for a turtle rather than a patch... This code makes no assumption about the number of turtles on each patch and stops if at least one such turtle is red.

```
ask turtles
[ if any? turtles-at 1 1 with [ color = red ] [stop]
]
```

Comment: `patch-at-heading-and-distance 90 1` can also be written as `patch-at 1 0`

Comment: in my case , if the color of the turtle in patch a head is red  the turtle must stop

Comment: still a  problem :'( " with expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number instead " 
if any? turtles-at 1 1 with [ color = red ] [stop] the problem in 1 1